# Split string to dict, where delimiter is part of value

Tags: python, parsing

I can't figure out a solution to this problem.

I have this example string:

```
test4 = "versandkostenfrei=Ja,delivery_time=sofort lieferbar,instantly_deliverable=true,spannung=7,2 Volt"
```

I'd like to convert this into a dict, where everything before the `=` sign is a key, and everything after is the value, up until the comma. The major problem is that some of the values (after the equal sign) contain a comma themselves. Also looking at the entire data set, it's possible that this last bit here `spannung=7,2 Volt` is somewhere in the middle of the string.

Desired output:

```
{
  "versandkostenfrei": "Ja",
  "delivery_time": "sofort lieferbar",
  "instantly_deliverable": "true",
  "spannung": "7,2 Volt"
}
```

It's not important if the bool value is also surrounded by double quotes or not.

Comment: Is the key always just alphanumeric and "_"?

Comment: Are you trying to parse arguments in a command line?

Comment: @gre_gor Yes, the keys don't have any anomalies.

Comment: @rschwieb It's a `.py` script. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Zettt No, I'm just asking what exactly you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to parse command line options with python.  There are probably easier ways to do that. Do you have any control over the incoming string at all or is that out of your hands?

Comment: @rschwieb I see. It's from a CSV file. One column has this data. They call it "tags", but this column has multiple data.

Comment: @Zettt Ok, that's very helpful. You get the _column_ back as a string?  A python csv reader typically returns rows, so I wonder how you're reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string with regex by keys with "=" (and possible prepended ","), with the key as a captured group.
This will create a list of alternating keys and values (first item will be an empty string).
Then you just collect them into key/value tuples to create a dict.

```
import re
test4 = "versandkostenfrei=Ja,delivery_time=sofort lieferbar,instantly_deliverable=true,spannung=7,2 Volt"
parts = re.split(",?([\w_]+)=", test4)
output = dict((parts[i], parts[i+1]) for i in range(1, len(parts), 2))
print(output)
```

This creates:

```
{
    'versandkostenfrei': 'Ja',
    'delivery_time': 'sofort lieferbar',
    'instantly_deliverable': 'true',
    'spannung': '7,2 Volt'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.split("="), [x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'[a-z_]+\=([A-Za-z ]+|([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?))+', test, re.DOTALL)]))
```

output:

```
{'versandkostenfrei': 'Ja',
 'delivery_time': 'sofort lieferbar',
 'instantly_deliverable': 'true',
 'spannung': '7,2 Volt'}
```

Comment: This assumes that the comma will only be used as a decimal separator. This fails to parse `list=one,two,tree,number=123`